# Rank to get the 2 highest values ​of each group

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a Rank function in Oracle SQL, but I'm not succeeding at all. I want to create a Rank on the result of a query that I've already created and that works well. This is my query:

```
select 
   MACHINE, 
   sum(DURATION/60)  AS Min,   
   OBSERVATION,
   to_char(min(START_DATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY_HH24') as date_hour,
   OBSERVATION || ' (' || rtrim(to_char(sum(DURATION/60), 'FM90.99'), '.') || '  Min) '   AS lost_prod 
 from MyTable

where TRUNC(START_DATE) = TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) and OBSERVATION IS NOT NULL 
group by  MACHINE, OBSERVATION, to_char(START_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY_HH24')
```

This query brings me a sum of the durations of each MACHINE and OBSERVATION for the same hour of day. My query brings the observations (concatenated with the distinct sum of their duration as LOST_PROD) for each hour of the day, but I want this query to show me only the two observations with the longest duration for each combination of machine, observation and date_hour. How do I do it?

My query above gives me the following result:

```
  MACHINE  |   MIN  |  OBSERVATION  |   DATE_HOUR    |      LOST_PROD
AAA            2.7      OFF RANGE     07/16/2023_10     OFF RANGE (2.7 Min)
AAA            3.1      LOW LEVEL     07/16/2023_10     LOW LEVEL (3.1 Min)
AAA            1.5      COLD FLEX     07/16/2023_10     COLD FLEX (1.5 Min)
AAA            1.1      LOW LEVEL     07/16/2023_11     COLD FLEX (1.1 Min)
AAA            4.7      OFF RANGE     07/16/2023_11     COLD FLEX (4.7 Min)
AAA            0.2      COLD FLEX     07/16/2023_11     COLD FLEX (0.2 Min)
TTT            1.9      LOW LEVEL     07/16/2023_11     COLD FLEX (1.9 Min)
TTT            1.4      RED ALERT     07/16/2023_11     COLD FLEX (1.4 Min)
TTT            1.1      COLD FLEX     07/16/2023_11     COLD FLEX (1.1 Min)
```

The expected result of my query with this Rank I want to do would be something like this:

```
MACHINE  |     MIN   |  OBSERVATION |   DATE_HOUR    |     LOST_PROD
AAA            2.7      OFF RANGE     07/16/2023_10     OFF RANGE (2.7 Min)
AAA            3.1      LOW LEVEL     07/16/2023_10     LOW LEVEL (3.1 Min)
AAA            1.1      LOW LEVEL     07/16/2023_11     COLD FLEX (1.1 Min)
AAA            4.7      OFF RANGE     07/16/2023_11     COLD FLEX (4.7 Min)
TTT            1.9      LOW LEVEL     07/16/2023_11     COLD FLEX (1.9 Min)
TTT            1.4      RED ALERT     07/16/2023_11     COLD FLEX (1.4 Min)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT machine, 
       min,   
       observation,
       TO_CHAR(date_hour, 'MM/DD/YYYY_HH24') as date_hour,
       lost_prod
FROM   (
  SELECT machine, 
         SUM(duration/60) AS Min,   
         observation,
         TRUNC(start_date, 'HH24') as date_hour,
         observation || ' ('
           || RTRIM(TO_CHAR(SUM(duration/60), 'FM90.99'), '.') || '  Min)'
           AS lost_prod,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY machine, TRUNC(start_date, 'HH24')
           ORDER BY SUM(duration/60) DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   MyTable
  WHERE  start_date >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)
  AND    start_date <  TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + 1
  AND    observation IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY
         machine,
         observation,
         TRUNC(start_date, 'HH24')
)
WHERE  rn <= 2;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (MACHINE, duration, OBSERVATION, start_date) AS
SELECT 'AAA', 2.7 * 60, 'OFF RANGE', TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '10' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA', 3.1 * 60, 'LOW LEVEL', TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '10' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA', 1.5 * 60, 'COLD FLEX', TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '10' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA', 1.1 * 60, 'LOW LEVEL', TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '11' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA', 4.7 * 60, 'OFF RANGE', TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '11' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA', 0.2 * 60, 'COLD FLEX', TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '11' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TTT', 1.9 * 60, 'LOW LEVEL', TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '11' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TTT', 1.4 * 60, 'RED ALERT', TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '11' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TTT', 1.1 * 60, 'COLD FLEX', TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '11' HOUR FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MACHINE | MIN | OBSERVATION | DATE_HOUR | LOST_PROD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 3.1 | LOW LEVEL | 07/05/2023_10 | LOW LEVEL (3.1 Min) |
| AAA | 2.7 | OFF RANGE | 07/05/2023_10 | OFF RANGE (2.7 Min) |
| AAA | 4.7 | OFF RANGE | 07/05/2023_11 | OFF RANGE (4.7 Min) |
| AAA | 1.1 | LOW LEVEL | 07/05/2023_11 | LOW LEVEL (1.1 Min) |
| TTT | 1.9 | LOW LEVEL | 07/05/2023_11 | LOW LEVEL (1.9 Min) |
| TTT | 1.4 | RED ALERT | 07/05/2023_11 | RED ALERT (1.4 Min) |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rbj2X1DV)

Comment: Exceptional solution!
I'll already going to mark your answer as the solution, but do you know if there's a way to make the LOST_PROD appear in descending order (based on the MIN) within each machine, observation and hour group?

Comment: @Req_7 `ORDER BY ... ASC` for ascending order (rather than `DESC`ending).